# Parsing Log File with bash script

Tags: bash, logging, awk, scripting, grep

Here is an example of a log file that I am trying to parse through.

```
2018-09-09 15:32:28 Alert Server1 Running Check TRIGGERED
+--------------------------------------+---------+
| ID        | host           | altID     | value |
+--------------------------------------+---------+
| 4als4234  | host1.mail.com | isRunning | true  |
| 5nsh3463  | host2.mail.com | isRunning | false |
+--------------------------------------+---------+
Instance: server
Alert ID: server_running
```

I would like to have a script that runs and formats the logs to look like this:

```
host: host1.mail.com 
altID: isRunning
value: true 
Alert ID: server_running

host: host2.mail.com 
altID: isRunning
value: false 
AlertID: server_running
```

I am knew to linux in general and my bash scripting knowledge is limited. I have tried using a few awk commands but I can't seem to get the format right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really need to use bash? If yes, awk is the right thing, you just need to learn a bit more of it, check `cut` too, may make things easier. If you don't need to use bash, consider using perl/python/ruby, it will be much easier to parse it :)

Comment: why is the Alert-ID 'server1_running" instead of 4als4234  ??

Comment: What have you tried? With the tags you've included in your question, I'd expect to see code in bash and awk. Please add your code, so that we can help you figure out what needs improvement. Also, is the order of output fields important, or could they be in column order? Do all input files have the exact same format, or might the number of hosts or initial log lines or other factors vary?

Comment: @stack0114106, that was a typo copying it over. However, I'm not really sure why that would make a difference in my question.

Comment: We need sample input that we can run a script on and if it produces the expected output then that script solves the problem, otherwise it doesn't. Typos in the input or output make your question less clear and mean we don't have anything to test against.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Perl solution:

```
$ cat alert.pl
open $INPUT,"<","$ARGV[0]" or die "No such file";
my $alertid ="";
while(my $row = <$INPUT>)
{
 if ($row=~m/^[|]\s*\d/m)
   {
     my @F = split(/\|/, $row);
     push @ht,"$F[2]";push @alt,"$F[3]";push @val,"$F[4]";
   }
 if ($row=~m/^Alert/m)
   {
     ($alertid = $row)=~s/(.*):(.*)/\2/g;
   }
}
foreach my $id (0..1)
{
print "host:$ht[$id]\n" ;
print "altID:$alt[$id]\n" ;
print "value:$val[$id]\n" ;
print "AlertID:${alertid}\n" ;
}
$ perl -f alert.pl alert.log  // Calling the perl script
host: host1.mail.com
altID: isRunning
value: true
AlertID: server_running

host: host2.mail.com
altID: isRunning
value: false
AlertID: server_running
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
gawk '
    /Alert.*TRIGGERED/ {alert_start = NR}
    alert_start && NR == alert_start + 4 { # the first data row of the table
        while (NF == 9) {
            ids[$2]["host"]  = $4
            ids[$2]["altID"] = $6
            ids[$2]["value"] = $8
            getline
        }
    }
    alert_start && /^Alert ID/ {
        for (id in ids)
            printf "host: %s\naltID: %s\nvalue: %s\nAlert ID: %s\n\n",
                ids[id]["host"], ids[id]["altID"], ids[id]["value"], $3
        delete ids
        alert_start = 0
    }
' log.file
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you said that the requirement `Alert-ID 'server1_running" instead of 4als4234` was a typo.
As far as I can see in the requirements something will work like

```
grep -E "true|false" inputfile |
   while read -r _ id _ host _ altID _ value _; do
      cat <<@
host: ${host}
altID: ${altID}
value: ${value}
Alert id: ${id}

@
   done
```

This will give the output

```
host: host1.mail.com
altID: isRunning
value: true
Alert id: 4als4234

host: host2.mail.com
altID: isRunning
value: false
Alert id: 5nsh3463
```